# wxpython code with rolling information

Tags: wxpython

I am trying to have my second panel roll out information (like how you see it on the bottom or top of the screen when you watch news, information constantly smothly rolls out). Except that, in my code, I would like to have this separate panel that comes out and it has multiple lines rolling out different information. Is there an effcient way to do this?  My code works but the characters do not come out at a smooth rate and eventually some of the letters start flickering.

```
import time
import wx


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent, title = 'Main Frame', size = (680,330))

        self.Center()

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self,size = (680,330))

        self.pnl1 = wx.Panel(self.panel, size = (680,330))
        self.pnl1.Show()
        self.pnl1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(red= 150, green= 0, blue= 0))

        my_label = wx.StaticText(self.pnl1, label = 'Click on this')
        font = wx.Font(14, wx.MODERN, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        my_label.SetFont(font)
        my_label.Center()

        my_label.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.func)

        #----------------------------------------------------------------------
        self.count1 = 0
        self.count2 = 0
        self.count3 = 0
        self.count4 = 0

        self.pnl2 = wx.Panel(self.panel, size=(800,300))
        self.pnl2.Hide()
        self.pnl2.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(red= 0, green= 190, blue= 0))

        self.lbl1 = ' Data ' * 10
        self.my_str1 = ''
        self.lbl2 = ' Info ' * 10
        self.my_str2 = ''
        self.lbl3 = ' bla bla ' * 10
        self.my_str3 = ''
        self.lbl4 = ' names ' * 10
        self.my_str4 = ''



        self.count1 = len(self.lbl1) - 1
        self.count2 = len(self.lbl2) - 1
        self.count3 = len(self.lbl3) - 1
        self.count4 = len(self.lbl4) - 1


        self.timer1 = wx.Timer(self)
        self.timer1.Start(200)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer1, self.timer1)

        self.timer2 = wx.Timer(self)
        self.timer2.Start(200)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer2, self.timer2)

        self.timer3 = wx.Timer(self)
        self.timer3.Start(200)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer3, self.timer3)

        self.timer4 = wx.Timer(self)
        self.timer4.Start(200)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer4, self.timer4)



        self.font = wx.Font(14, wx.MODERN, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)

        #----------------------------------------------------------------------

    def func(self, event):
        self.pnl1.Hide()
        self.pnl2.Show()

    def OnTimer1(self,event):
        if self.count1 < 0:
            self.count1 = len(self.lbl1) - 1
            self.my_str1 = ''

        if self.count1 >= 0:
            self.my_str1 =  self.lbl1[self.count1] + self.my_str1
            self.my_label1 = wx.StaticText(self.pnl2, label = self.my_str1, pos = (0,0))
            self.my_label1.SetFont(self.font)

        self.count1 = self.count1 - 1

    def OnTimer2(self,event):
        if self.count2 < 0:
            self.count2 = len(self.lbl2) - 1
            self.my_str2 = ''   

        if self.count2 >= 0:
            self.my_str2 =  self.lbl2[self.count2] + self.my_str2
            self.my_label2 = wx.StaticText(self.pnl2, label = self.my_str2 , pos=(0,40))
            self.my_label2.SetFont(self.font)   

        self.count2 = self.count2 - 1

    def OnTimer3(self,event):
        if self.count3 < 0:
            self.count3 = len(self.lbl3) - 1
            self.my_str3 = ''   

        if self.count3 >= 0:
            self.my_str3 =  self.lbl3[self.count3] + self.my_str3
            self.my_label3 = wx.StaticText(self.pnl2, label = self.my_str3 , pos=(0,80))
            self.my_label3.SetFont(self.font)   

        self.count3 = self.count3 - 1

    def OnTimer4(self,event):
        if self.count4 < 0:
            self.count4 = len(self.lbl4) - 1
            self.my_str4 = ''   

        if self.count4 >= 0:
            self.my_str4 =  self.lbl4[self.count4] + self.my_str4
            self.my_label4 = wx.StaticText(self.pnl2, label = self.my_str4 , pos=(0,120))
            self.my_label4.SetFont(self.font)   

        self.count4 = self.count4 - 1   


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
#run code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame(None)
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for the ticker control: http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.ticker-module.html Or perhaps the NewsTicker widget that was posted to the wxPython mailing list a year ago would be better: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/wxpython-users/HKEN12uCPnI/t2nyTxCEnakJ